# Natural sort Wordpress post titles (alphabetically and numerically)?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

Is there any possible way to sort a new Wordpress post query by the title, but numerically instead of alphabetically?

I have some titles that have a lot of the same name alphabetically, then have a number afterwards, so of course for example Wordpress is putting `title12` ahead of `title1`.

```
$args = array( 
'orderby'=> 'title', 
'order' => 'ASC',
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I know we have this functionality to sort titles in ascending order, but it does not sort titles like that:

```
Title 1
Title 2
```

Please let me know if we any work around using WP query ?
Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this immediately after your code above:

```
usort($loop->posts, function($a,$b) {
   return strnatcmp($a->title, $b->post_title);
});
```

Comment: +1, but anonymous functions are supported on PHP 5.3.6+